# Testing private attributes/methods

Tags: php, phpunit

I have the following method that I want to test:

```
public function getJSONData(ExtClass $ext) {
   $obj = new DataClass();
   $obj -> setData($ext -> something);
   $sendObj = new SendClass();
   $sendObj -> send($obj);
   echo $obj -> getJSONData();
}
```

The method generates some JSON data based on the parameters of $ext object. I can test its output by passing different ExtClass objects, like this:

```
public function testGetJSONData() {
   $extObj = new ExtObject('aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc');
   $mObj = new MainClass();
   $jsonData = $mObj -> getJSONData($extObj);
   $this -> assertEquals(1, $jsonData -> d);
   // etc
}
```

But then I wouldn't be able to test all different things that happen on the way - DB inserts, structures created, etc.

For example, let's say I have the following `DataClass` class:

```
class DataClass {

   private $arr1;
   private $val2;

   public function setData($something) {
      $this -> _setArr();
      $this -> _setVal();
   }

   private function _setArr() {
      $this -> arr1 = array('fdfds');
   }

   private function _setVal() {
      $this -> saveToDatabaseSomething($this -> arr1 -> something);
      $this -> val1 = 'gfgdfgdfgfd';
   }

}
```

I am not able to test this class because everything is private and all different actions are based on one input.

What's the proper way to test this?

Answer (score 0):

You should never need to test private attributes and methods and if you think you need it, your code is not testable enough.

> test all different things that happen on the way - DB inserts, structures created, etc.

For a unit test you would mock these things (See: https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)

In your case it looks like you would need to mock the `SendClass`, which seems to do some external stuff. But unfortunately you are creating it within the method under test. It is a good practice to separate object creation from object usage, for example like this:

```
class ClassToTest
{
    private $sendObj;
    public function __construct(SendClass $sendObj)
    {
        $this->sendObj = $sendObj;
    }
    public function getJSONData(ExtClass $ext) {
       $obj = new DataClass();
       $obj -> setData($ext -> something);
       $this->sendObj -> send($obj);
       echo $obj -> getJSONData();
    }
}
```

Then you can write your unit test like this:

```
public function testGetJSONData()
{
    $input = new ExtClass('something');
    $expectedSent = new DataClass('something');
    $expectedJson = "{'something':'something'}";

    $mockSendObj = $this->getMock(SendClass::class, ['send']);
    $mockSendObj->expects($this->once())
        ->method('send')
        ->with($expectedSent);
    $subject = new ClassToTest($mockSendObj);
    $actualJson = $subject->getJSONData($input);
    $this->assertEquals($expectedJson, $actualJson);
}
```

And the actual behavior of `SendClass` is tested in another unit test for that class only.

---

There is another test type where you want to test the interaction between your units, the *integration test*. For such a test you would not mock the collaborators, but you would also not test internals like calls to private methods, but for example test what actually gets written to the database.